# Неверное отображение изображений в TableView [Вопрос закрыт]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, realm

**Как должно работать:**
Контроллер получает данные из Realm и передает значения в соответствующие поля строки (имя и изображение).

**В чем проблема:**
При инициализации, функция cellForRowAt выполняется дважды, в результате чего изображения отображаются неверно. Не могу понять, почему происходит повторное выполнение. При выполнении программы с помощью брейкпоинтов ошибок не возникает.

**Код контроллера:**

```
class FavoriteTableVC: UITableViewController {    

    var data: Results<GetPhotoResults>?
    private let networkService = NetworkService()

    var token: NotificationToken?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        navigationItem.title = TitlesIdentifiers.favoritePhotos.rawValue

        tableView.register(FavoriteCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: CellsIdentifiers.favoriteCell.rawValue)

        pareTableAndRealm()
    }

    private func pareTableAndRealm() {
        guard let realm = try? Realm() else { return }
    
        self.data = realm.objects(GetPhotoResults.self)
    
        token = data?.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }

            switch changes {
            case .initial(_):
                tableView.reloadData()
            case let .update(_, deletions, insertions, modifications):
                tableView.beginUpdates()

                tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .automatic)
                tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .automatic)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .automatic)

                tableView.endUpdates()
            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view Data Source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let count = data?.count else { return 0 }
        return count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellsIdentifiers.favoriteCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as? FavoriteCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        guard let data = self.data else { return UITableViewCell() }
        guard let name = data[indexPath.row].user?.name else { return UITableViewCell() }
        guard let url = data[indexPath.row].urls?.small else { return UITableViewCell() }
    
        cell.nameLabel.text = name
        print(cell.nameLabel.text!)
    
        if let url = URL(string: url) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                AF.download(url, method: .get).responseData { response in
                    print("url: \(url)")
                    guard let data = response.value else { return }
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.photoImageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Сохранение данных в Realm:**

```
class SaveDataInRealm {

    static func saveData (_ data: GetPhotoResults) {
        do {
            var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
            config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
        
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
        
            realm.beginWrite()
            realm.add(data, update: .modified)
            try realm.commitWrite()
        
            print(realm.configuration.fileURL!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Вывод данных в консоль (количество строк в таблице - 4):**

[image: Вывод данных в консоль]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена:

В методе pareTableAndRealm() в части

```
case .initial(_):
    tableView.reloadData()
```

заменил tableView.reloadData() на функцию loadData().

```
private func loadData() {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        self.data = realm.objects(GetPhotoResults.self)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```